# What is the difference between the transfer and transferFrom function in an ERC721 contract

Tags: web3js, erc-721

Using `web.js`, I am trying to transfer `erc721` tokens across different addresses.
In case of `cryptokitties`, I can do the transfer using `transfer` function only while in case of `cryptoheroes`, I can use the same contract but do the transfer only using `transferFrom`.

What exactly is the difference between the two?
How can I write a generic code which will work when I want to transfer the tokens for all ERC721 contract? Or do I need to have the contract ABI for each contract?

Answer (score 3):

The function `transferFrom` in token contracts refers to the transfer of tokens that you do not own, but rather have been approved to spend. It is used together with the `approve` function, when an address establishes a certain allowance of tokens for another address to spend for them. Hence, when using `transferFrom` you establish what address the tokens that you are spending are coming from, whereas `transfer`  is just for your own tokens.

And regarding interaction between contracts, you could implement a function to allow transfers of tokens from other contracts directly in your smart contract. However, web3.js is not going to help you achieve that if the function is not present in the smart contract itself. For that, you'd have to specify the contract addresses and ABIs to interact with separately.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `transfer` in ERC-721. Source:

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

`transferFrom` is superior because you may have authority from multiple people to send any given NFT. That means a transfer is ambiguous whether it is coming from yourself or from someone else that authorized you to send it.

> *But I know I’m sending it from myself because I’m the one who currently owns it*

Not really. “Currently” is a funny concept on the blockchain. So you cannot be sure of the exact state of the system when you make a transaction. This is why `transferFrom` is designed to atomically check for you.

—-

So why does CryptoKitties have bare `transfer`? Because CK was deployed before the final EIP was standardized.

Comment: "There is no transfer" -> this is false if I look in the link or I haven't understand what you mean.

Comment: @David Perhaps you are seeing `event Transfer(...)`, that is an event, not a function. Or are you seeing something else?

Comment: function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;

Comment: Got it. The OP differentiated a `transfer(...)` and `transferFrom(...)` function. You found the `transferFrom` and there is no `transfer` (in the standard).